# How can i add 0 to a generated string to obtain correct formatting?

Tags: string, formatting, output

I have to generate some ternary numbers with specific formatting . How can i specify to add 0 in string before a given number generated to have the same  output format between the lines i generate ?

i tried with an if which get the input parameter comparison (number of columns ) to the output in order to correct the wrong formatted lines .

```
public class TernaryGenerator {
    private int number ;
    private double max ;

    public TernaryGenerator(int number) {

        this.number = number;
        this.max = Math.pow(3, this.number)-1 ; 
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= this.max ; i++ ) {
            System.out.println(convToTernary(i));
        }

    }
    private String convToTernary(int num) {

        String result = "";
        int reste;

        while (num > 0) {
            reste = num % 3;
            result += " "+reste;
            num /= 3;
        }
        if (result.length() < this.number)
            result += " "+ 0;
        return new StringBuffer(result).reverse().toString();
    }


    public static void main(String [] args) {
        TernaryGenerator tern = new TernaryGenerator(2);
    }

}
```

i obtain :

```
1 
2 
1 0 
1 1 
1 2 
2 0 
2 1 
2 2
```

instead of expected:

```
0 1 
0 2 
1 0 
1 1 
1 2 
2 0 
2 1 
2 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself by replacing :

```
if (result.length() < this.number)
            result += " "+ 0;
```

by

```
while (result.length()  < this.number *2 )
        result += " "+ 0;
```

formatting of columns is now correct for any value .